# Jaydata as KendoDataSource doesn't automatically refresh on new record add

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, jaydata

I'm using jaydata to manage a client only data store.  The data is received via a SignalR Broadcast.  The received data is buffered in memory.  Once a second the memory buffer is flushed to the jaydata store and saved.

The Kendo Grid that is bound to the jaydata store doesn't automatically update.  I need to call the read method on the dataSource once the jaydata saveChanges method completes.  The below code is the method that is called when the timer fires.

```
$scope.updateGrid = function () {
    if ($scope.allowUpdate) {
        var data = $scope.scribeMessages.splice(0, $scope.scribeMessages.length);
        if (data.length > 0) {
            scribeDb.Messages.addMany(data);
            scribeDb.saveChanges().then(function () { $scope.scribeGrid.dataSource.read(); });
        }
    }
};
```

In my Kendo Grid, I have defined the dataSource as follows:

```
    dataSource: scribeDb.Messages.asKendoDataSource({
        pageSize: 20,
        sort: [{ field: "SequenceId", dir: "desc" }]
    })
```

I have defined the entity, the entity set, and the scribed as:

```
$data.Entity.extend("ScribeMessage", {
    SequenceId: { type: "string", required: true, key: true, computed: false },
    ScribeId: { type: "string", required: true },
    Environment: { type: "string", required: true },
    LogLevel: { type: "integer", required: true },
    Program: { type: "string", required: true },
    Subject: { type: "string", required: false },
    Message: { type: "string", required: false },
    MachineName: { type: "string", required: true },
    InstanceId: { type: "string", required: false },
    ComponentId: { type: "string", required: false },
    Exception: { type: "string", reguired: false },
    ServerTime: { type: "date", required: true },
    ClientTime: { type: "date", required: true },
    User: { type: "string", required: true }
});

$data.EntityContext.extend("ScribeDatabase", {
    Messages: { type: $data.EntitySet, elementType: ScribeMessage }
});

var scribeDb = new ScribeDatabase({ provider: "indexedDb", databaseName: "ScribeMessages" });
```

I was expecting the grid bound datasource to automatically detect that the underlying data store has changed.

Is it expected to have to force the datasource to read?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It is not expected to detect the changes. This is the same behaviour as if you had your grid connected to a server, you would not be notified of changes. You either have build in polling, or a push notification on your own.

JayData does provide events for when data changes that you can hook into, for example I often use

`context.Dogs.addEventListener('afterUpdate', function(){ alert('doggy updated'); });`

In the event you can tell your grid's datasource to reload. But make sure the user isn't currently editing something... I believe this is why JayData does not force a reload, as they can't be sure the user is not in the middle of doing some action on the grid.

Have fun, JayData and Kendo are a bit of a volatile marriage. :)